# "scrutinisation"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to express the method for presenting information that is found when a person is under scrutiny.

The way investigate becomes investigation, I was hoping that scrutinise would become scrutinisation.

Unfortunately, my research tells me that there is no such word, and it brings me to 'under scrutiny"

So far I only came up with "probe" as an alternative.

Any ideas which other word could be used?

Comment: Someone under scrutiny is being investigated.

Comment: scrutiny is scrutinisation. Scrutiny can be scrutinising as investigation can be investigating. I don't understand.

Comment: I would avoid scrutinization, and go with scrutinizing.

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford American Dictionary does give an entry for the noun "scrutinization" in its entry on the verb "to scrutinize". Note the 'z' instead of the 's'!

Using an 's' is preferred in British English, but you won't find it if you're looking in American dictionaries or using American spell checkers. This is part of the general spelling difference between American and British English, in which American English prefers that verbs end in '-ize' while British English prefers '-ise'. According to Mary Norris's book *Confessions of a Comma Queen*, you can thank Benjamin Franklin for that bit of trivia, as well as for many other spelling differences between American and British English ('color' vs 'colour', 'theater' vs 'theatre', and so on).

Source definition:

**scrutinize** | ˈskro͞otnˌīz |

verb [with object]
examine or inspect closely and thoroughly: customers were warned to scrutinize the small print.

DERIVATIVES

scrutinization | ˌskro͞otn-iˈzāSHən | noun

scrutinizer | ˈskro͞otnˌīzər | noun